# trigger create new database after update with old and new variables dbForge

Tags: mysql

i want to create new database with old and new data by type as: id_old, id_new. how to create trigger maybe whose creatig this later? sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: AS I have said in your [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265432/create-trigger-create-new-table-when-old-table-is-updated-dbforge-using-deleted) - **DDL are not allowed in triggers**.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and vote to close this question. please put more effort in asking a good question, instead of asking different questions about the same thing.